# Retrieve the last 5 lines of a file and move it to a new file

Tags: unix

I am new to unix.I want to retrieve the last 5 lines of a file and move it to a new file.How can I do this?Can we use tail command as a part of move command?Please help me

Comment: This is a rather simple problem and solutions for this are available here on Stack Overflow. Please search for a solution first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `tail` to retrieve the last five lines:

```
tail -n 5 /path/to/file
```

Use `>` to write the output of the command to a new file:

```
tail -n 5 /path/to/file > /path/to/new/file
```